# How do I solve the differential equation $f(t) - f''(t) = \frac{\pi}{2e^t}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$f(t) - f''(t) = \frac{\pi}{2e^t}$$

--

I would have been able to solve it if the right side was a constant.

Can someone please fully solve it. I feel really dumb right now..I've been stuck on it for a very long time

Comment: I don't get the logic of why we're substituting it as $e^{\lambda t}$

Answer (score 6):

Take $g(t)=f(t)-f'(t)$ and get $g(t)+g'(t)=\frac{\pi}{2e^t}$ or $$\frac d{dt}(e^tg(t))=\frac{\pi}2$$
That is $f(t)-f'(t)=\frac{\pi t}{2e^t}$ which implies $$\frac d{dt}(-e^{-t}f(t))=\frac {\pi t}{2e^{2t}}$$ or $$f(t)=-\frac{\pi}2e^t\int te^{-2t}dt+c$$

Comment: I'll get $f(t) - f'(t) = \frac{\pi t}{2e^t}$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dt}(-e^{-t}f(t)) =e^{-t}(f(t)-f'(t))$

Comment: Can you please fully solve it :) I've been stuck for a really long time

Comment: Thank you, can you tell me why we ignored the integration constant in the second step? it gives a diff result if we consider it.

Comment: Oh never mind..stupid me..the result remains the same. Happy new year :)

Comment: Happy new year to you too! Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Hint: let $y=ze^{-t}$.
Which differential equation does $z$ satisfy?

Why this choice:

We see that the term on the right hand side is of the form $g(t)e^{-t}$, where $g(t)$ is a constant in this case. What I want to do is get rid of this $e^{-t}$ term so that I will get an easy differential equation. But I know that $(e^{-t})'=-e^{-t}$, so I know that no matter how many times I differentiate any function of the form $ze^{-t}$, I will still get a factor $e^{-t}$, so that I will be able to divide both the right hand side and the left hand side by this term, which will lead to an easy to solve differential equation.

Note: it is only a coincidence in this case that the right hand side is of the form $e^{\lambda t}$. In general, with the method I gave, you can solve the equation for any power of $e$. So it would work for $e^{3t}$ or $e^{-5t}$. There are shortcuts for the case $e^{\lambda t}$, though.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

The r.h.s. has the form $C\mathrm e^{-t}$, and $-1$ is a root of the *characteristic equation*. Try  a particular solution of the form:
$$y_0(t)=Ct\,\mathrm e^{-t}, \quad C\in\mathbf R. $$

Answer (score 2):

***Hint:***

Substitute $g(t)=f(t)+f'(t)$

then your equation become a first order equation:

$$f(t) +f'(t)-f'(t)-f''(t)=h(t)$$
$$g(t)-g'(t)=h(t)$$

Answer (score 2):

It's good that you don't get the logic of substituting it as $e^{\lambda t} $. The right approach is not learning such cheap tricks but to solve the equation step by step.

If we use the symbol $D$ to denote differentiation with respect to $t$ and powers of $D$ to denote repeated differentiation so that $$Df(t) =\frac{d} {dt} f(t), D^{n} f(t) =\frac{d^{n} } {dt^{n}} f(t) $$ then we can think of polynomials in $D$ with constant coefficients so that $$(a_{0}D^{n}+a_{1}D^{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}D+a_n)f(t)=\\ a_{0}f^{(n)}(t)+a_{1}f^{(n-1)}(t)+\dots+a_{n-1}f'(t) +a_{n} f(t) $$ This way of thinking has certain advantages in the sense that we can then add / multiply such polynomials according to the usual rules of operations with polynomials (this needs to be proved by the way and its not difficult to do so).

---

The equation in your question can then be written as $$(1-D^2)f(t)=(\pi/2)e^{-t}\tag{1}$$ The right way to solve such equations is to understand that a linear equation of type $$(D+a)p(t)=q(t)\tag{2}$$ can always be solved by multiplying the above equation with $e^{at} $. Note that $$D(e^{at} p(t)) = e^{at} Dp(t) +a e^{at} p(t) =e^{at} (D+a)p(t) $$ and hence multiplying equation $(2)$ by $e^{at} $ gives us $$D(e^{at}p(t))= e^{at} q(t) $$ Integrating this equation with respect to $t$ gives us $e^{at} p(t) $ and hence $p(t) $. Thus we need to solve $(1)$ by reducing it to a series of equations of type $(2)$. How? Just by factorizing the polynomial occurring in the equation $(1)$.

---

Thus we rewrite $(1)$ as $$(1-D)(1+D)f(t)=(\pi/2)e^{-t}$$ and set $$(1+D)f(t)=g(t)\tag{3}$$ so that $$(1-D)g(t)=(\pi/2)e^{-t} \tag{4}$$ The given equation $(1)$ is thus reduced to a set of two linear equations $(3),(4)$ which are easily solved in succession as described earlier. Thus multiplying $(4)$ by $e^{-t}$ we get $$-D(e^{-t} g(t)) =(\pi/2)e^{-2t}$$ On integrating we get $$e^{-t} g(t) =\frac{\pi} {4}e^{-2t}+c$$ or $$g(t) =ce^{t} +\frac{\pi} {4}e^{-t}$$ Equation $(3)$ can now be solved in similar manner by multiplying it with $e^{t} $ and we then have $$D(e^{t} f(t)) = ce^{2t}+\frac{\pi}{4}$$ On integrating we get $$e^{t} f(t) =\frac{ce^{2t}}{2}+\frac{\pi t} {4}+d$$ or $$f(t) =Ae^{t} +Be^{-t}+\frac{\pi} {4}te^{-t}$$ where $A=c/2, B=d$ are arbitrary constants.

---

It should be noted that the above procedure involves writing the equation using differential operator $D$ and factoring the polynomial in $D$ (also known as *characteristic polynomial* of the equation) down to the linear factors and handling each factor one by one.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use characteristic equation $1-\lambda^2=0$ and find the general solution, then with $y=Ate^{-t}$ find particular solution.

Comment: Happy new year :)

Answer (score 1):

I use for simplicity $K=\frac {\pi} 2$

$$f(t) +f'(t)-f'(t)-f''(t)=Ke^ {-t}$$
Multiply by $e^t$
$$f(t)e^t +f'(t)e^t-(f'(t)e^t+f''(t)e^t)=K$$

$$(f(t)e^t)'-(f'(t)e^t)'=K$$

integrate both side
$$(f(t)e^t)-(f'(t)e^t)=Kt+C$$
Divide by $e^{2t}$
$$\frac {f(t)e^t-f'(t)e^t}{e^{2t}}=e^{-2t}(Kt+C)$$

Then,

$$-(\frac {f(t)}{e^{t}})'=e^{-2t}(Kt+C)$$
Integrate again,
$$f(t)=-e^{t}\int e^{-2t}(Kt+C)dt$$